Посоветуйте библиотеку или API для работы с городами и странами
Я пишу код на python, и столкнулся с задачей: мне надо, чтобы пользователь выбирал свою страну, и затем появлялся список городов в его стране. Через какие готовые библиотеки или API можно реализовать такой функционал? Заранее спасибо!
